# Make a sidebar that allows to navigate in one page

Tags: docusaurus

I would like to know if Docusaurus has the following feature. For example in https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/demo/prettydocs/start.html, the content of the document is in one page. When we scroll down, we see the change in the sidebar. Whereas in Docusaurus, it seems that we need to click on  "Next" to see the next part and the change in the sidebar.

Is it possible to make a sidebar in Docusaurus that allows to navigate in one page?

(I'm new to Docusaurus. I have posted the same question in Discord app, but nobody replied.)

Answer (score 0):

Docusaurus maintainer here. There's no way to achieve this now without reimplementing such logic in your own docs plugin. Why not just write all your docs on a single page? The table of contents on the right will be the same as the left table of contents in the website you linked.